# The dependency array of useEffect, useCallback, useMemo

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, usecallback, react-usememo

I'm so confused of the dependency of React Hooks.
Here's the example:

```
const memorizeValue = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      count,
      setCount,
    }
  }, [count, setCount])
```

In React documentary:

> Note
>
> The array of dependencies is not passed as arguments to the function.
> Conceptually, though, that’s what they represent: every value
> referenced inside the function should also appear in the dependencies
> array. In the future, a sufficiently advanced compiler could create
> this array automatically.

`count` and `setCount` both inside useMemo's callback, if i doesn't pass `setCount` in the dependency array, the eslint won't warning me,  but `count` will, so what's the difference?
why don't need pass `setCount`? `setCount` is inside useMemo, isn't it?

here's the codesandbox link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-forked-xfupk?file=/src/Demo1/index.js:254-363

I think i maybe misunderstand the document. Somebody point it out, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [useState docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

> **Note**
>
> React guarantees that `setState` function identity is stable and won’t
> change on re-renders. This is why it’s safe to omit from the `useEffect`
> or `useCallback` dependency list.

Assuming `setCount` is the updater function of a `useState` hook then it's guaranteed to be a stable reference.